# How to calculate Density in clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am working with data-set having 2 co-ordinates. Currently I am calculating density by at first calculating total distance from each point to other points and then dividing it by total points. I want to know is this the correct method to calculate density as I am not getting desired result.

This is the cluster file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45772222/samp.txt

this cluster should have 3 cluster -> 2 ellipse and one pipe connecting them
any idea how can I separate them?

Answer (score 0):

Now that is a total toy example.

DBSCAN cannot separate clusters of different densities that touch each other. By definition of density connectedness, they must be separated by an area of low density. In your toy example, the two large clusters are actually **connected by an area of *higher* density**.

So essentially, this is an example of non-density based clusters... If you want density based clustering to be able to separate these clusters, you must reduce the density of the connecting bar to have a lower density than the clusters. (But maybe don't even bother to use such toy examples at all)

Comment: i just want to know how to calculate the density in a given cluster with n data points